# Should I provide my list of allowed field values in their own dedicated table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, relational-database

I have a model 'Person' representing a database table 'people':

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :age, numericality: { only_integer: true }
end

def change
  create_table :people do |t|
    t.string :first_name
    t.string :second_name
    t.integer :age
    t.string :phone_number
    t.text :description
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

I want to add an additional field called 'star_sign', which can only hold the name of one of the twelve signs of the Zodiac (Capricorn, Leo, Scorpio, etc).

What would be the correct/best practice way for me to implement this?

1) To create a separate table, star_sign, containing a record for each of the twelve signs, and have a belongs_to relationship from models 'Person' to 'StarSign' and a has_many relationship from 'StarSign' to 'Person'?

or

2) To write some validation code in the class definition for model 'Person' that would force my 'star_sign' field in the 'people' table to only accept one of the twelve exact strings that match the names of the Zodiac signs?

If it is 2, could someone give me the appropriate code to do this? Or even if 1 is the best solution, I'd still be interested to see the code that would be used to implement 2.

Comment: This is the perfect occasion to use the new `ActiveRecord::Enum` class! See the documentation here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html -- Also, since time goes by, the `age` column should probably be `birth_year` (or `birth_date`) so that the age can be computed automatically instead of stored. It would be better than running a script once a year to increment each `age` value in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the best solution is to use the functionality provided by the ActiveRecord::Enum class.

I add this code to my 'Person' model:

```
enum star_sign: [ :leo, :capricorn, :aries, :libra, :scorpio, :taurus, :virgo, :cancer, :gemini, :aquarius, :sagittarius, :pisces ]
```

And I add this field to my 'people' table:

```
t.integer :star_sign
```

It's necessary to declare the field to be of type integer when using enum, because the way we let the system know which Zodiac sign to store is with its corresponding element index number. So for example, 0 for "leo" or 11 for "pisces".